# How can I "force" macro expansion before calling another macro?

Tags: macros, expansion

I am using the listings package and am doing a mapping of syntax names. Basically I want to do this:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\syntaxnamefor{m}{
  ... % this command if given `xhtml` returns `html`, if given `py` returns `python`
}
\NewDocumentCommand\setsyntax{m}{
  \lstset{language=\syntaxnamefor{#1}}
}
```

Now the problem is that in the `\lstset` call the argument does not get fully expanded. I get the following error:

```
! Package Listings Error: language \syntaxnamefor {xhtml} undefined
```

E.g. the listings package gets the string `\syntaxnamefor {xhtml}` as its argument instead of getting its expansion `html` as its argument. I've tried around with `\edev` and `\expandafter` but that's some really complicated stuff...

Comment: Regardless of how you can force (or have to force) expansion in `\lstset`, note that a command defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` is never expadanble. You want `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` are not expandable, use `\newcommand` or `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`.

Comment: Or use simply `\def`.

Comment: @wipet I searched all my latex manuals and could find no such command, what does it do?